# Evaluating developers

Tags: evaluation

I am a technical team leader of a small programming team, working on a project for an external client.

I was recently asked to produce written evaluations of my team members. I feel uncomfortable doing this, because I don't see myself as a management person and never thought of my colleagues much deeper than "A is reliable and B is a lazy bum".

But I am expected to produce more elaborate stuff to be read by actual managers, and my manager hinted that the purpose of this is rather to test my evaluation skills.

Any hints or resources on how to produce a quality evaluation? Are there standardized forms? How should I address this?

Thank you.

Comment: Remember, it's about the business, not the person.

Comment: @George, not really... if he said "I don't know about the person, but the business is great" he wouldn't be doing what he is being asked to do.  If you mean don't get personal, that's somewhat closer to true, however if the person is obnoxious and a very disruptive personality that should be mentioned.  At the end of the day these reviews are about evaluating the person.

Comment: 6 up-votes, 4 stars and some good discussion and then a bunch of people close it.  What a shame.  If this guy can't post this question here, where can he?  Lighten up people, this is all part of being a programmer.

Comment: A +6 question closed as not programming related?  This is very programming related as we all have to work with programmers on a daily basis and I think we'd all love to see the "right" people get the praise.

Comment: @wheaties: Votes does not mean the question is programming related.  Writing evaluations is HR/managerial, doesn't matter if you oversee programmers, librarians, or cats.

Comment: @ponies - I am not HR and I am not a manager, I don't *oversee* people. I am a programmer and dealing with unusual requests is part of a programmer's life. And at least some people found this topic interesting so I don't see the urgency to just close it down. Very frustrating experience for my first question on this site...

Comment: @Mike W. Don't let it discourage you.  Do a search on the website.  There's a ton of these types of questions.  Follow some of the advise you have here and best luck to you.  Btw, evaluate yourself first so you find out your biases and basis for determining "good."

Answer (score 3):

I have found that [Joel's Professional Development Ladder](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/ladder.html) and [this construx site](http://construx.com/?nid=244) provided great advice on how to start. It helps to understand the various knowledge areas and what developers are expected to know and do. You can then evaluate developers on how competent they are in various knowledge areas and assign them a level accordingly.

You of course have to evaluate their work ethic and attitude etc which have nothing to do with development as such.

Answer (score 2):

Tough question! I would suggest you first look back at evaluations that have been performed by your manager on YOU. This is usually a good example of what you are expected to produce for your team mates. If you have not had any formal evaluation yet, I suggest you look to your HR department, or management for a copy of a standard template for such purposes. Most large companies have them.

Evaluating team members can be tricky, especially as a team leader and not a 'front line' manager. Remember the following,

- Be honest, with them and yourself
- Evaluate based on performance not gut feeling, or emotion
- Never ever evaluate someone better simply because you 'like' them or have empathy for their situation. It always comes back to you in the end.

Edit:
Some further things I thought of, been awhile since I did evals as a team lead..

- When evaluating performance, look at not only what the person needs to improve, but also what they have done well. Try to present both sides of the story (even if you feel the person is a lazy bum)
- Look at quantifiable results.. what has the person PRODUCED and how useful was it to the team as a whole. Remember, even if they pump out thousands of lines of code, that doesn't mean it was all useful, maintainable or even worth the time.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

First thing, don't be intimidated by the task.  Second, you are a team lead, so your opinion of the people counts; it may be a test, but you should be up to it.  Third, if you were doing this informally over a coffee and your boss asked you about someone you would probably have no trouble chatting for a few minutes about your observations of them and what you thought were their strengths and weaknesses.  That's what you should write down in your review notes.

Ask your boss if there is a standard format - if you are in a large organisation HR might have forms and/or systems in place for these sorts of reviews.  Otherwise, just give him a paragraph or two in plain English (or your language of choice) on what you think.

You can add colour to your reports by citing work they have done and where they have succeeded or failed.

Some golden rules...

- don't get personal
- try and be objective and fair
- don't hide the truth, however uncomfortable

Good luck, it's all part of stepping up to be a manager and is fun in a way - your opinion is counting.

Comment: lol, I guess we either think alike, or you copied and pasted half of my answer!

Comment: I am guessing we have both been doing this a while

Comment: Simon, Chris, thanks for the advice but it's a small company and there is no standard template or process for this thing. I'm having quite a bit of trouble finding a suitable template online. Unless I get lucky about this, perhaps somebody could recommend me one, since I truly don't feel up to devising one from scratch.

Comment: Don't worry about creating a template, just start jotting your observations down.  A structure will emerge once you have covered two or three people.  Deal with them separately in a paragraph each.  You're over-thinking it, just give your honest opinion in plain English in a straightfoward letter style document.  If your boss wants it another way when he sees it you can chop it around then.  Get the content down.

Answer (score 0):

You could conduct a 360 degree feedback with your team (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360-degree_feedback), motivating each team member to give feedback to his colleagues (and you).

Comment: er, no, I wouldn't advise doing this.  It will spread fud.

Comment: I agree that this may happen. Then you should first try to build up a environment that is able to handle feedback and critics.